# Any Hausdorff topology on a finite-dimensional vector space is equivalent to the usual one

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I am trying to understand the proof of this statement.

> Any Hausdorff topology on a finite-dimensional vector space with
> respect to which vector space operations are continuous is equivalent
> to the usual one.

Source: [https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~cass/research/pdf/TVS.pdf](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecass/research/pdf/TVS.pdf)

In the proof it is stated that:

> It remains to show that the inverse of $f$ is continuous. For this, it
> suffices to show that $f(B(1))$ contains a neighbourhood of $0$.

My Question is:
Why does it suffice to show that $f(B(1))$ contains a neighborhood of $0$?

Here the proposition in detail:

> Any Hausdorff topology on a finite-dimensional vector space is
> equivalent to the usual one
>
> Proof: A basis of $V$ determines a linear isomorophism $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow V$, which is continuous by the assumptions on the topology
> of $V$. By definition of continuity, if $U$ is any neighborhood of $0$
> in $V$ there exists some disk $B(r)$ with $f(B(r))\subseteq U$.
>
> It remains to show that the inverse of $f$ is continuous. For this, it
> suffices to show that $f(B(1))$ contains a
> neighborhood of $0$. . . .

Comment: @geetha290krm The ball of radius $1$ with center $0$

Comment: Since your map $f$ is linear, and if $f(B_0(1))$ contains a neighborhood of $0$. You could write $B_x(1)$ as $x+B_0(1)$, and by linearity of $f$, $f(x+B_0(1))=f(x)+B_0(1)$. Thus for $B_x(1)$ you get that $f(B_x(1))$ contains a open neighborhood of $x$.

Comment: @geetha290krm But if its finite dimensional one can identify it with $\mathbb{K}^n$

Comment: @geetha290krm I will do, I just thought that maybe that is easier for everyone.

Comment: @geetha290krm I did write everything down to the part where the statement I am confused about is stated.

Comment: Peter's hint can easily be completed to get an answer. Show that the image of any open set is open using that hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is well-known that a linear map $\phi : V \to W$ between TVS $V,W$ is continuous iff it is continuous at $0$. I shall give a proof later.

To prove that $g := f^{-1} :  V \to \mathbb R^n$ is continuous, it therefore suffices to show that for each open neighborhood $W$ of $0$ in $\mathbb R^n$ there exists an open neighborhood $W'$ of $0$ in $V$ such that $g(W') \subset W$. The latter is equivalent to $W' \subset f(W)$.

Assume that $f(B(1))$ contains an open neighborhood $W_0$ of $0$ in $V$. There exists $r > 0$ such that $B(r) \subset W$. Then $W' := rW_0$ is an open neighborhood of $0$ in $V$ such that
$$W' = rW_0 \subset r f(B(1)) = f(rB(1)) =f(B(r)) \subset f(W) .$$

Let us finally prove that a linear $\phi : V \to W$ which is continuous at $0$ is continuous at all $v \in V$.

Let $W'$ be an open neighborhood of $\phi(v)$ in $W$. Then $W'' = W' - \phi(v)$ is an open neighborhood of $0$ in $W$ and there exists an open neighborhood $V''$ of $0$ in $V$ such that $\phi(V'') \subset W''$. Clearly $V' = V'' + v$ is an open neighborhood of $v$ in $V$ and we have
$$\phi(V') = \phi(V'' + v) = \phi(V'') + \phi(v) \subset W'' + \phi(v) = W'.$$